# MSI Laptop - Keyboard not working when fn lock is on

Tags: laptop, keyboard, fn-key

Whenever I turn on the fn-lock on my laptop, my keyboard stops to respond. This happens to both Ubuntu and Windows, I'm dual-booting so I don't think this is something related to OS, should be some hardware or firmware thingy. Mine is MSI Modern 14, just bought over a month ago. Has anyone experienced this before and how to fix this? Googling seems not to work. Thanks.

Update: this happens after I start using a wireless mouse, Zadez M356. One strange thing is the mouse was received as a keyboard in Windows. Removing the mouse from the list of devices doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the keyboard may have a wiring or circuit defect.

Since the laptop is new, ask for Warranty support  / replacement.

You can ask them if the keyboard is a field replaceable part when you contact them.

Also, it is important to use warranty when the machine is new, as any attempt to fix that is not sanctioned by the manufacturer may void the warranty.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer. I have updated the question. Should it be the case that the mouse was the problem?

Comment: I read the update and you said removing the mouse does not solve the issue. So ask the Manufacturer for warranty support.

Comment: I amended my answer to note that unsanctioned self fixes may void the warranty.